# Keep Firefox from displaying plugins needed for an html object

Tags: html, firefox

I have a Firefox plugin that adds some optional features to my web app. I'm using an object tag in the html to embed the plugin. However, if a user doesn't have the plugin Firefox displays the message:

> Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page.

Since the plugin is just for optional features I don't want this message displayed even if they don't have the plugin.

Is there anything I can to do keep Firefox from displaying this message?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible, since I'd imagine the check for required plug-ins is solely a user-enabled feature. Could you perhaps check for the plug-in being installed and, if found, then add the optional content to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try detecting the presence of the plugin with the [`navigator.plugins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins) object using Javascript, before injecting the `object` needed for the additional features to work dynamically. For instance, this script will check for the presence of the Flash plugin:

```
for(var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++){
    if(navigator.plugins[i].description.indexOf('Shockwave Flash') !== -1){
       console.log(navigator.plugins[i]);
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yi, always a pleasure. (I removed the link comment, since it's a bit redundant now).